# How to toggle wifi / bluetooth in Macbook Air with Windows 7 installed

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, bluetooth, macbook-air

I'm writing this on a MacBook Air 13" (the ones just released), but I have a problem. BootCamp provides no easy way of turning off the bluetooth or wifi radios, and nor are there any hotkey combinations on the keyboard, nor any hard or soft switches on the body to toggle these radios.

As I'll be travelling a lot with this machine, what's the best way for me to comply with the cabin service crews' instructions and disable the radios before takeoff, and reenable them after landing?